# Vuex promise reject returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, es6-promise

I want the promise reject to return the error to my method but the response is empty inside my methods then() function, how can i get the error response to be returned to my method for further use or even inside the catch function.

My vuex action

```
//authAction 
login({ commit }, payload) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      user.login(payload.user.email, payload.user.password)
        .then(response => {

          const user = response.data.user;

          // If there's user data in response
          if (user) {
            const payload = [user]

            commit('AUTH_SUCCESS', payload, { root: true })

            resolve(response)
          } else {
            reject({ message: "Sorry, cant login right now" })
          }

        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.status)
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  }
```

My method

```
// Login method
login() {
      if (!this.checkLogin()) return;

      this.$vs.loading();

      const payload = {
        checkbox_remember_me: this.checkbox_remember_me,
        user: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      };

      this.$store
        .dispatch("auth/login", payload)
        .then(res => {
          this.$vs.loading.close();
          console.log(res);
       })
        .catch(error => {
          this.$vs.loading.close();
          this.$vs.notify({
            title: "Error",
            text: error.message,
          });
        });
    }
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `login()` should return the promise if you want the caller to use it.

Comment: I figured out that i dont need promise wrapper since i am using axios

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is to 1. dispatch an action whenever an error is thrown which updates state 2. watch state change in view and do something with it